# Problem with wininet C++

Tags: c++, wininet

Can anyone find problem in this function?
My application makes several requests and if first request is using SSL, app crashes on some computers(on mine 4 computers + vmware it works ok without crash).

Here is code

```
char Buffer[1024];
DWORD dwRead;
string data;

string Request(string method, string host, string file, string headers,
               string post, bool debug, bool SSL)
{
    HINTERNET hSession, hDownload, hRequest;
    DWORD flag;
    DWORD port;

    data.empty();

    //SSL or not + flag :)
    if (SSL)
    {
        port = INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT;
        flag = INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE; // FLAG_SECURE
    }
    else
    {
        port = INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
        flag = INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD; //FLAG_RELOAD
    }

    char * postdata;
    postdata = new char[post.size() + 1];
    strcpy(postdata, post.c_str());
    char * headersdata;
    headersdata = new char[headers.size() + 1];
    strcpy(headersdata, headers.c_str());

    //Actual request
    hSession
            = InternetOpen(
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; sl; rv:1.9.2.11) Gecko/20101012 Firefox/3.6.11",
                    INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hSession)
    {
        hDownload = InternetConnect(hSession, host.c_str(), port, NULL, NULL,
                INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
        if (hDownload)
        {
            hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hDownload, method.c_str(), file.c_str(),
                    "HTTP/1.1", NULL, NULL, flag, 0);
            if (hRequest)
            {
                if (strlen(headersdata) && strlen(postdata))
                {
                    HttpSendRequest(hRequest, headersdata, strlen(headersdata),
                            postdata, strlen(postdata));
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpSendRequest(hRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Writing HTML response in data buffer
    while (InternetReadFile(hRequest, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), &dwRead))
    {
        if (dwRead == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        Buffer[dwRead] = 0;
        data += Buffer;
    }

    //Debug :)
    if (debug)
    {
        ofstream dbgfile;
        dbgfile.open("debug.html");
        dbgfile << data;
        dbgfile.close();
    }

    //Close handles
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hDownload);
    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);

    return data;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error is given when the crash occurs? Access violation? Some other error code?

Comment: Error is **This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.**

Too bad it doesnt happen here so I could debug :(

Comment: you could try remote debugging...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a buffer overflow with `Buffer`.

Consider these lines:

```
while (InternetReadFile(hRequest, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), &dwRead))
```

and

```
Buffer[dwRead] = 0;
```

Since you pass `sizeof(Buffer)` as *dwNumberOfBytesToRead* parameter in the former line, maximum value of `dwRead` is `sizeof(Buffer)`. If such a case occurs, the latter line will write one byte past the end of `Buffer`. Your data layout makes it unlikely to cause a crash (but it's pure chance!), unless you have Runtime Security Checks enabled, which can explain the crash message.

Also, as far as I can remember, the "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way" message is displayed either by `assert()` or `terminate()` in Microsoft implementation. (I don't have MSVC available at the moment and can't verify it). I don't see the reason for either one in this piece of code, so if it's not the `Buffer` overflow, look for it in other places too.

Comment: Thanks for telling me i fixed it :)
But still it doesnt solve the problem... :(
I don't know why it crashes only on some machines not on all...

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove strlen:

```
HttpSendRequest(hRequest, &headers.front(), headers.size(),
                 &post.front(), post.size());
```

In this case the function will be a little more secure.

Anyway, consider using [Crash Dump Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In this case you will able to check the callstack from the crash dump gotten from 'some computers'.