# C++ wininet undefined reference even with -lwininet linker flag

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, wininet

I'm new with WinInet and have following simple C++ code:

```
void DoIt(std::string& host, std::string& username, std::string& password) {
    HINTERNET hInternet;
    HINTERNET hFtpSession;
    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hInternet == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
    } else {
        hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, host.c_str(), INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, username.c_str(), password.c_str(), INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
        if (hFtpSession == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
        } else {
            if (!FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, "C:\\temp\\ftp\\myFile.txt", "/myFile.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0)) {
                std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But compiler's output is:

```
Info: Configuration "Debug" uses tool-chain "MinGW GCC" that is unsupported on this system, attempting to build anyway.
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -std=c++11 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
C:\Users\u007\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFEaWlK.o: In function `Z4DoItRSsS_S_':
C:\projects\ftp-test\Debug/../main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `_imp__InternetOpenA@20'
C:\projects\ftp-test\Debug/../main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `_imp__InternetConnectA@32'
C:\projects\ftp-test\Debug/../main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `_imp__FtpPutFileA@20'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(I link to `wininet.lib` library in Eclipse's linker)
[image: Adding <code>wininet.lib</code> in Eclipse]

(I also tried to add `-lwininet` option to compiler but it does nothing)

I use following software:

- OS: `Windows 10 x64`
- IDE: `Eclipse Neon 3`
- Compiler: `MinGW (rubenvb-4.8-stdthread) 4.8.1 20130324 (prerelease)`

I saw following links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887372/how-to-fix-this-error-undefined-reference-to-imp-internetopena) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769097/wininet-h-not-compiling-using-gnu-gcc-compiler-with-code-blocks) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885181/problem-with-wininet-c) but nothing there helps me.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: There is no C code visible. Why using the C language tag?

Comment: Possibly `WinInet` use C but no C++ code

Comment: Try `"C:\MinGW-Installation-Folder\lib\libwininet.a"` instead of `"wininet.lib"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the g++ compile line it's is missing the library to link to (wininet). You need in eclipse to add that library so your program link to it.

Comment: I add the screenshot where you can see that `WinInet` library was added to my project as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351712/how-to-add-a-library-to-an-eclipse-project

Comment: are you sure that eclipse is able to find wininet, I seel that you do not have any -L configured in the screenshot

Comment: I even tried to specify full path to wininet.lib file in -l linker options

Comment: You need to put the path in the library path section -L (capital L), have you tried that?

Comment: I just noticed the warning you getting: MINGW GCC is not detected, so basically. It's your problem, eclipse is probably using another config GCC cross compiler instead to compile your program and this is why any change on MINGW GCC have no effect on your compilation.